# Flip image for usage on button

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have some buttons in my app declared like this:

```
let infoButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.InfoLight) as UIButton
infoButton.addTarget(self, action: "toggleInfo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
```

Is there a way to mirror the image from a system defined button itself (e.g. vertically) before assigning it to my NavigationBar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical flip of CGContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135631/vertical-flip-of-cgcontext)

Comment: I don´t think so. I want to flip a graphic that´s build in - here a system type button.

Comment: You might want to try downloading a template PSD and export the desired buttons for yourself. For example from: https://dribbble.com/shots/2255601-iOS-9-Complete-UI-free-PSDs-for-iPhone-5-6-and-6-Plus

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.05);
    UIView *view = [buttonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
    view.transform = transform;
```

Check out how they animated it here: https://gist.github.com/bergholdt/0db2d2264e29e3646e9c